# What is the difference between sigaction and signal?

Tags: c, signals, posix

I was about to add an extra signal handler to an app we have here and I noticed that the author had used `sigaction()` to set up the other signal handlers. I was going to use `signal()`. To follow convention I should use `sigaction()` but if I was writing from scratch, which should I choose?

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Use [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) unless you've got very compelling reasons not to do so.

The [`signal()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html) interface has antiquity (and hence availability) in its favour, and it is defined in the C standard.  Nevertheless, it has a number of undesirable characteristics that `sigaction()` avoids - unless you use the flags explicitly added to `sigaction()` to allow it to faithfully simulate the old `signal()` behaviour.

1. The `signal()` function does not (necessarily) block other signals from arriving while the current handler is executing; `sigaction()` can block other signals until the current handler returns.
2. The `signal()` function (usually) resets the signal action back to `SIG_DFL` (default) for almost all signals.  This means that the `signal()` handler must reinstall itself as its first action.  It also opens up a window of vulnerability between the time when the signal is detected and the handler is reinstalled during which if a second instance of the signal arrives, the default behaviour (usually terminate, sometimes with prejudice - aka core dump) occurs.
3. The exact behaviour of `signal()` varies between systems — and the standards permit those variations.

These are generally good reasons for using `sigaction()` instead of `signal()`.  However, the interface of `sigaction()` is undeniably more fiddly.

Whichever of the two you use, do not be tempted by the alternative signal interfaces such as
[`sighold()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sighold.html),
[`sigignore()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigignore.html),
[`sigpause()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigpause.html) and
[`sigrelse()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigrelse.html).
They are nominally alternatives to `sigaction()`, but they are only barely standardized and are present in POSIX for backwards compatibility rather than for serious use.  Note that the POSIX standard says their behaviour in multi-threaded programs is undefined.

Multi-threaded programs and signals is a whole other complicated story.  <s>AFAIK, both `signal()` and `sigaction()` are OK in multi-threaded applications.</s>

[Cornstalks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1287251/cornstalks) [observes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231912/what-is-the-difference-between-sigaction-and-signal/232711?noredirect=1#comment43835195_232711):

> The Linux man page for [`signal()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) says:
>
> *The effects of **`signal()`** in a multi-threaded process are unspecified.*
>
> Thus, I think `sigaction()` is the only that can be used safely in a multi-threaded process.

That's interesting.  The Linux manual page is more restrictive than POSIX in this case.  POSIX specifies for [`signal()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html):

> If the process is multi-threaded,  or if the process is single-threaded and a signal handler is executed other than as the result of:
>
> - The process calling `abort()`, `raise()`, `kill()`, `pthread_kill()`, or `sigqueue()` to generate a signal that is not blocked
> - A pending signal being unblocked and being delivered before the call that unblocked it returns
>
> the behavior is undefined if the signal handler refers to any object other than `errno` with static storage duration other than by assigning a value to an object declared as `volatile sig_atomic_t`, or if the signal handler calls any function defined in this standard other than one of the functions listed in [Signal Concepts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04).

So POSIX clearly specifies the behaviour of `signal()` in a multi-threaded application.

Nevertheless, `sigaction()` is to be preferred in essentially all circumstances — and portable multi-threaded code should use `sigaction()` unless there's an overwhelming reason why it can't (such as "only use functions defined by Standard C" — and yes, C11 code can be multi-threaded).  Which is basically what the opening paragraph of this answer also says.

Comment: This description of `signal` is actually of the Unix System V behavior. POSIX allows either this behavior or the much more sane BSD behavior, but since you can't be sure which one you'll get, it's still best to use `sigaction`.

Comment: unless you use the flags explicitly added to sigaction() to allow it to faithfully simulate the old signal() behaviour. What flags would those be (specifcally)?

Comment: @AlexFritz: Primarily `SA_RESETHAND`, also `SA_NODEFER`.

Comment: [The Linux man page says](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html): `The effects of signal() in a multithreaded process are unspecified.` Thus, I think `sigaction` is the only that can be used safely in a multithreaded process.

Comment: @Cornstalks: Interesting — see update.  In view of Linux undefining the behaviour, you're correct, which ties in with the original opening paragraph of the answer.

Comment: @Jonathan, could you suggest, what should one use to write portable code dealing with signals that should work on non-POSIX systems too?

Comment: @BulatM. If you can't use `sigaction()`, then you're essentially obliged to use the Standard C specification for `signal()`. However, that gives you an extremely impoverished set of options for what you can do. You can: modify (file scope) variables of type `volatile sig_atomic_t`; call one of the 'quick exit' functions (`_Exit()`, `quick_exit()`) or `abort()`; call `signal()` with the current signal number as the signal argument; return.  And that's it. Anything else is not guaranteed to be portable. That's so stringent that most people ignore those rules — but the resulting code is dodgy.

Comment: That is not interesting. If you look for the **old** POSIX standard of `signal()`, then it is the same as in the Linux manual page.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/signal.html

Comment: For completeness, and to help me and others, can you add a brief demo of registering a callback for both `signal()` and `sigaction()` to catch a couple basic signals, ex `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM`? This would be extremely helpful to see how to use them both, as `sigaction()` looks very confusing in comparison, whereas `signal()` is extremely easy to use. Therefore, until reading this answer I always favored `signal()`, and now that I've read this answer, I'd like to see a solid and correct example of how to use `sigaction()`.

Comment: Excellent `sigaction()` demo from GCC themselves: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sigaction-Function-Example.html; and excellent `signal()` demo from GCC themselves: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Basic-Signal-Handling.html#Basic-Signal-Handling. Notice that in the `signal` demo they avoid changing the handler from ignore (`SIG_IGN`) if that's what it was previously intentionally set to.

Comment: And my answer detailing it and providing extensive code samples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231912/what-is-the-difference-between-sigaction-and-signal/58815445#58815445

Answer (score 15):

### In short:

`sigaction()` (see [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) and [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/sigaction.html)) is good and well-defined, but is a POSIX function and so it works only on Linux or POSIX systems. `signal()` (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/signal) and [here](https://cplusplus.com/reference/csignal/signal/)) is bad and poorly-defined, but is a C standard function and so it works on anything.

### What do the Linux man pages have to say about it?

`man 2 signal` (see it [online here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html)) states:

> The behavior of `signal()` varies across UNIX versions, and has also varied historically across different versions of Linux.  Avoid its use: use `sigaction(2)` instead.  See Portability below.

> Portability
>
> The only portable use of `signal()` is to set a signal's disposition to
> `SIG_DFL` or `SIG_IGN`.  The semantics when using `signal()` to establish a
> signal handler vary across systems (and POSIX.1 explicitly permits
> this variation); **do not use it for this purpose.**

In other words: do *not* use `signal()`. Use `sigaction()` instead!

This position is reiterated in the next line which states (emphasis added):

> POSIX.1 solved the portability mess by specifying `sigaction(2)`, which provides explicit control of the semantics when a signal handler is invoked; **use that interface instead of `signal()`**.

### What does GCC think?

From https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Basic-Signal-Handling.html#Basic-Signal-Handling (emphasis added):

> Compatibility Note: As said above for `signal`, **this function should be avoided when possible. `sigaction` is the preferred method**.

So, if both Linux and GCC say not to use `signal()`, but to use `sigaction()` instead, that begs the question: how the heck do we use this confusing `sigaction()` thing!?

### Usage Examples:

Read GCC's EXCELLENT `signal()` example here: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Basic-Signal-Handling.html#Basic-Signal-Handling

And their EXCELLENT `sigaction()` example here: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sigaction-Function-Example.html

After reading those pages, I came up with the following technique for `sigaction()`:

#### 1. `sigaction()`, since it's the right way to attach a signal handler, as described above:

```c
#include <errno.h>  // errno
#include <signal.h> // sigaction()
#include <stdio.h>  // printf()
#include <string.h> // strerror()

// Format: const char *, unsigned int, const char *
#define LOG_LOCATION __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__ 
#define LOG_FORMAT_STR "file: %s, line: %u, func: %s: "

/// @brief      Callback function to handle termination signals, such as 
///             Ctrl + C
/// @param[in]  signal  Signal number of the signal being handled by this 
///             callback function
/// @return     None
static void termination_handler(const int signal)
{
    switch (signal)
    {
    case SIGINT:
        printf("\nSIGINT (%i) (Ctrl + C) signal caught.\n", signal);
        break;
    case SIGTERM:
        printf("\nSIGTERM (%i) (default `kill` or `killall`) signal caught.\n", 
            signal);
        break;
    case SIGHUP:
        printf("\nSIGHUP (%i) (\"hang-up\") signal caught.\n", signal);
        break;
    default:
        printf("\nUnk signal (%i) caught.\n", signal);
        break;
    }

    // DO PROGRAM CLEANUP HERE, such as freeing memory, closing files, etc.

    
    exit(signal);
}

/// @brief      Set a new signal handler action for a given signal
/// @details    Only update the signals with our custom handler if they are NOT
///     set to "signal ignore" (`SIG_IGN`), which means they are currently
///     intentionally ignored. GCC recommends this "because non-job-control
///     shells often ignore certain signals when starting children, and it is
///     important for children to respect this." See
///     https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Basic-Signal-Handling.html#Basic-Signal-Handling
///     and
///     https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sigaction-Function-Example.html.
///     Note that termination signals can be found here:
///     https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html#Termination-Signals
/// @param[in]  signal  Signal to set to this action
/// @param[in]  action  Pointer to sigaction struct, including the callback 
///     function inside it, to attach to this signal
/// @return     None
static inline void set_sigaction(int signal, const struct sigaction *action)
{
    struct sigaction old_action;

    // check current signal handler action to see if it's set to SIGNAL IGNORE
    sigaction(signal, NULL, &old_action);
    if (old_action.sa_handler != SIG_IGN)
    {
        // set new signal handler action to what we want
        int ret_code = sigaction(signal, action, NULL);
        if (ret_code == -1)
        {
            printf(LOG_FORMAT_STR "sigaction failed when setting signal to "
                   "%i; errno = %i: %s\n", 
                   LOG_LOCATION, signal, errno, strerror(errno));
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //...

    // Register callbacks to handle kill signals; prefer the Linux function
    // `sigaction()` over the C function `signal()`: "It is better to use
    // sigaction if it is available since the results are much more reliable."
    // Source:
    // https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Basic-Signal-Handling.html#Basic-Signal-Handling
    // and
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231912/what-is-the-difference-between-sigaction-and-signal/232711#232711.
    // See here for official gcc `sigaction()` demo, which this code is modeled
    // after:
    // https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sigaction-Function-Example.html

    // Set up the structure to specify the new action, per GCC's demo.
    struct sigaction new_action;
    new_action.sa_handler = termination_handler; // set callback function
    sigemptyset(&new_action.sa_mask);
    new_action.sa_flags = 0;

    // SIGINT: ie: Ctrl + C kill signal
    set_sigaction(SIGINT, &new_action);
    // SIGTERM: termination signal--the default generated by `kill` and
    // `killall`
    set_sigaction(SIGTERM, &new_action);
    // SIGHUP: "hang-up" signal due to lost connection
    set_sigaction(SIGHUP, &new_action);

    //...
}
```

#### 2. And for `signal()`, even though its not a good way to attach a signal handler, as described above, it's still good to know how to use it.

Here's the GCC demonstration code copy-pasted, as it's about as good as it's going to get:

```c
#include <signal.h>

void
termination_handler (int signum)
{
  struct temp_file *p;

  for (p = temp_file_list; p; p = p->next)
    unlink (p->name);
}

int
main (void)
{
  …
  if (signal (SIGINT, termination_handler) == SIG_IGN)
    signal (SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
  if (signal (SIGHUP, termination_handler) == SIG_IGN)
    signal (SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);
  if (signal (SIGTERM, termination_handler) == SIG_IGN)
    signal (SIGTERM, SIG_IGN);
  …
}
```

### The main links to be aware of:

1. Standard Signals: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Standard-Signals.html#Standard-Signals
2. Termination Signals: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html#Termination-Signals
3. Basic Signal Handling, including official GCC `signal()` usage example: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Basic-Signal-Handling.html#Basic-Signal-Handling
4. Official GCC `sigaction()` usage example: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sigaction-Function-Example.html
5. Signal sets, including `sigemptyset()` and `sigfillset()`; I still don't understand these exactly, but know they are important: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Signal-Sets.html

### See also:

1. My answer on ["How to manually send any signal to any running process" and "How to trap any signal in your program" (ex: in Bash)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/692443/114401).
2. TutorialsPoint C++ Signal Handling [with excellent demo code]: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_signal_handling.htm
3. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/signal_h.htm

Comment: I don't understand `sigemptyset` either

Answer (score 10):

To me, this below line was enough to decide:

> The sigaction() function provides a
>   more comprehensive and reliable
>   mechanism for controlling signals; new
>   applications should use sigaction()
>   rather than signal()

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/signal.html#tag_03_690_07

Whether you're starting from scratch or modifying an old program, sigaction should be the right option.

Answer (score 6):

signal() is standard C, sigaction() is not.

If you're able to use either (that is, you're on a POSIX system), then use sigaction(); it's unspecified whether signal() resets the handler, meaning that to be portable you have to call signal() again inside the handler. What's worse is that there's a race: if you get two signals in quick succession, and the second is delivered before you reinstall the handler, you'll have the default action, which is probably going to be to kill your process.
**sigaction()**, on the other hand, is guaranteed to use “reliable” signal semantics. You need not reinstall the handler, because it will never be reset. With SA_RESTART, you can also get some system calls to automatically restart (so you don't have to manually check for EINTR).
**sigaction()** has more options and is reliable, so its use is encouraged.

Psst... don't tell anyone I told you this, but POSIX currently has a function bsd_signal() which acts like signal() but gives BSD semantics, which means it's reliable. Its main use is for porting old applications that assumed reliable signals, and POSIX does not recommend using it.

Comment: POSIX does not have a function `bsd_signal()` — some POSIX implementations may have the function, but POSIX itself does not contain such a function (see [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm)).

Answer (score 5):

They're different interfaces for OS's signal facilities. One should prefer using sigaction to signal if possible as the signal() has implementation-defined (often race prone) behavior and behaves differently on Windows, OS X, Linux and other UNIX systems.

See this [security note](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/SIG01-CPP.+Understand+implementation-specific+details+regarding+signal+handler+persistence) for details.

Comment: I just looked at the glibc source code and signal() just calls into sigaction().  Also see above where the MacOS man page claims the same.

Comment: that is good to know.  I've only ever seen signal handlers used to close things neatly before exiting so I wouldn't usually be relying on behaviour to do with reinstalling the handler.

Answer (score 2):

From the **`signal(3)`** man page:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>  This signal() facility is a simplified interface to the more
>  general sigaction(2) facility.
> ```

Both invoke the same underlying facility. You should presumably not manipulate the response the a single signal with both, but mixing them shouldn't cause anything to break...

Comment: That's not in my man page!  All I get is "DESCRIPTION The  signal()  system call installs a new signal handler for the signal with number signum. "   I need to upgrade to the _useful_ man pages package.

Comment: That's off of the Mac OS X 10.5 pages.

Comment: Also verified from the source code of glibc.  signal() just calls sigaction()

Comment: This isn't true on all implementations of signal, however.  If you want to mandate "sigaction" behavior, don't rely on this assumption.

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest using sigaction() over signal() and would like to add one more point.
sigaction() gives you more options such as pid of the process that died (possible using the siginfo_t struct).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use signal() since it's more portable, in theory at least.  I'll vote up any commenter who can come up with a modern system that doesn't have a POSIX compatibility layer and supports signal().

Quoting from the [GLIBC documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libc/Signal-and-Sigaction.html):

> It's possible to use both the signal and sigaction functions within
>   a single program, but you have to be careful because they can
>   interact in slightly strange ways.
>
> The sigaction function specifies more information than the signal
>   function, so the return value from signal cannot express the full
>   range of sigaction possibilities. Therefore, if you use signal to
>   save and later reestablish an action, it may not be able to
>   reestablish properly a handler that was established with sigaction.
>
> To avoid having problems as a result, always use sigaction to save
>   and restore a handler if your program uses sigaction at all. Since
>   sigaction is more general, it can properly save and reestablish any
>   action, regardless of whether it was established originally with
>   signal or sigaction.
>
> On some systems if you establish an action with signal and then
>   examine it with sigaction, the handler address that you get may not
>   be the same as what you specified with signal. It may not even be
>   suitable for use as an action argument with signal. But you can rely
>   on using it as an argument to sigaction. This problem never happens
>   on the GNU system.
>
> So, you're better off using one or the other of the mechanisms
>   consistently within a single program.
>
> Portability Note: The basic signal function is a feature of ISO C,
>   while sigaction is part of the POSIX.1 standard. If you are
>   concerned about portability to non-POSIX systems, then you should
>   use the signal function instead.
>
> > Copyright (C) 1996-2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> >
> > Permission is granted to copy, distribute and/or modify this
> >     document under the terms of the GNU Free Documentation License,
> >     Version 1.2 or any later version published by the Free Software
> >     Foundation; with no Invariant Sections, with no Front-Cover Texts,
> >     and with no Back-Cover Texts. A copy of the license is included in
> >     the section entitled "GNU Free Documentation License".

Answer (score 0):

From man page [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

> A process-directed signal may be delivered to any
>     one of the threads that does not currently have the signal blocked.
>     If more than one of the threads has the signal unblocked, then the
>     kernel chooses an arbitrary thread to which to deliver the signal.

And I would say this "issue" exists for [signal(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) and [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html).
So be careful with signals and pthreads.

... and [signal(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) seems to call [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) underneath in Linux with glibc.