# So what's the difference between sigaction() and signal()?

Tags: c, signals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between sigaction and signal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231912/what-is-the-difference-between-sigaction-and-signal)

It seems to me that both of them can be used to register a callback for a specific signal.

How do you choose which one to use?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231912/what-is-the-difference-between-sigaction-and-signal).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLPI

> UNIX systems provide two ways of
>   changing the disposition of a signal:
>   `signal()` and `sigaction()`. The
>   sigaction() system call is an
>   alternative to signal() for setting
>   the disposition of a signal. Although 
>   sigaction() is somewhat more  complex
>   to use than  signal(), in return it
>   provides greater flexibility.

`sigaction` is also more portable than `signal`. Also, with `sigaction` you can specify signal handlers that receive additional arguments (`sa_sigaction` versus `sa_handler`).

```
/* can be installed by signal / sigaction */
void(*) (int);

/* can be installed by sigaction only */
void(*) (int, siginfo_t *, void *);
```

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, the difference (except interface :) and portability) is in behavior after signal is caught:

> If the disposition is set to a function, then first either the disposition is reset to SIG_DFL, or the signal is blocked (see Portability below), and then handler is called with argument signum.  If invocation of the handler caused the signal to be blocked, then the signal is unblocked upon return from the handler.

And, also I'd like to repeat the same as the man page says:

> The behavior of signal() varies across Unix versions, and has also varied historically across different versions of Linux.  Avoid its use: use sigaction(2) instead.