# SetConsoleCtrlHandler equivalent for Unix/Linux C++

Tags: c++, linux, winapi

Does anybody know an equivalent of the Windows [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms686016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function for Linux/UNIX OS? (Specifically, for a wxWidgets application.)

Comment: What research have you performed so far?

Comment: From what I can tell, POSIX signals are the closest match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ['signal()' function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csignal/).

Here's an example:

```
#include <signal.h>

bool stop = false;

void app_stopped(int sig)
{
   // function called when signal is received.
   stop = true;
}

int main()
{
   // app_stopped will be called when SIGINT (Ctrl+C) is received.
   signal(SIGINT, app_stopped);

   while(false == stop)
      Sleep(10);
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigaction.html) avoids some pitfalls that can be common with `signal()`, and should be preferred..

Comment: Or rather [sigaction](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigaction.html).

Comment: inb4: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231912/what-is-the-difference-between-sigaction-and-signal

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thanks for the reference, very informative.  This is one of those things that generally once in place tend to not be modified, so the last time I did this I hadn't heard of `sigaction`.