# catching interrupt signals in mono on linux

Tags: .net, mono, porting

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ControlEventHandler e, bool add);
```

I use this to catch and manage console interrupts, specifically `Ctrl. + C`.
It works well under Windows 7 with .NET,
however I want to port this to `mono` on `arch-linux`.
When running it (regardless if built on Windows or directly on the linux machine with xbuild) I get

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: SetCtrlHandler
at (wrapper managed-to-native) rzs_slim.consoleControl:SetConsoleCtrlHandler (rzs_slim.ControlEventHandler, bool) //rzs_slim is the project, consoleControl the class
at [ctor of consoleControl]
at [Main]
```

How can I use this call to native code in mono? Can I reference the .dll in mono?

**EDIT**:
Actually, since this is a console-application I was able to achive the desired effect by subscribing my cleanup-function to the [`Console.CancelKeyPress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cancelkeypress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-Event

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825985/setconsolectrlhandler-equivalent-for-unix-linux-c. You need to search for the alternative in OS which you use it.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I even saw that when researching before asking, but thought my usage of .Net and mono might change the rules a bit.