# (Why) does raise reset the signal handler?

Tags: visual-c++, signals, abort, msvcrt

It would appear that the implementation of [`raise(sig)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwwzkt4c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) resets the handler installed with [`signal(sig, handlerFunction)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), that is, in a multithreaded program, the first thread to call [`abort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k089yyh0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) *will* call the custom `handlerFunction`, but if any other threads then calls abort, this other thread will just call `exit(3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the behavior of signal + raise is specified as such. From Wikipedia's article on [`sigaction`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigaction):

> ... replacement of the unreliable and deprecated `signal()` function. Signal
>   handlers installed by the `signal()` interface will be uninstalled
>   immediately prior to execution of the handler. Permanent handlers must
>   therefore be reinstalled by a call to `signal()` during the handler's
>   execution, causing ...

So it seems this is expected behavior. (Of course, the MSDN docs seem to completely fail to mention this.)

Question here on SO: [What is the difference between sigaction and signal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231912/what-is-the-difference-between-sigaction-and-signal)