# When I catch a signal with signal(SIGINT,f), is f executed in parallel?

Tags: c, signals

I have C code like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>


void handler_function(int);
int i=0;
int j=0;
int main() {
    signal(SIGINT,f);
    while(1) {
     /* do something in variable `i` */
    }
}

void f(int signum) {
     /* do something else on variable `i` */
}
```

Can it produce a data race? i.e. is `f` executed in parallel (even in a multithread machine) to the `main`. Or maybe is the `main` stopped until `f` finish its execution?

Comment: Standard 7.14.1.1,7: 

*Use of this function in a multi-threaded program results in undefined behavior. The
implementation shall behave as if no library function calls the signal function.*

Comment: @self. I don't think he's necessarily asking about calling `signal` from a multi-threaded program, although if so, then the paragraph you quoted would certainly seem to apply. I think he's just asking whether a signal handler behaves as if it was a separate thread, or if it runs in the main thread. My understanding is that it does the latter. That is, the main thread stops on whatever instruction it was executing, then the signal handler runs, and then it goes back to executing the next instruction, right where it left off.

Comment: The [glibc manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Signal-Handling) has a pretty good chapter on how signals work. Perhaps you might start there. Not sure how that might relate to platforms that don't use glibc though, so take that into consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you use the [`raise()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/raise.html) from Standard C or [`kill()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html) with the value from `getpid()` as the PID argument, signal events are asynchronous.

In single-threaded code on a multi-core machine, it means that you cannot tell what is happening in the 'do something to variable `i`' code.  For example, that code might have just fetched the value from `i` and have incremented it, but not yet saved the incremented value.  If the signal handler function `f()` reads `i`, modifies it in a different way, saves the result and returns, the original code may now write the incremented value of `i` instead of using the value modified by `f()`.

This is what leads to the many constraints on what you can do in a signal handler.  For example, it is not safe to call `printf()` in a signal handler because it might need to do memory allocation (`malloc()`) and yet the signal might have arrived while `malloc()` was modifying its linked lists of available memory.  The second call to `malloc()` might get thoroughly confused.

So, even in a single-threaded program, you have to be aware and very careful about how you modify global variables.

However, in a single-threaded program, there will be no activity from the main loop while the signal is being handled.  Indeed, even in a multi-threaded program, the thread that receives (handles) the signal is suspended while the signal handler is running, but other threads are not suspeded so there could be concurrent activity from other threads.  If it matters, make sure the access to the variables is properly serialized.

See also:

- [What is the difference between `sigaction()` and `signal()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231912/what-is-the-difference-between-sigaction-and-signal/)
- [Signal concepts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04).

Answer (score 2):

First of all according to the man page of `signal()` you should not use `signal()` but `sigaction()`

> The behavior of signal() varies across UNIX versions, and has also varied historically across different versions of Linux.  Avoid its use: use sigaction(2) instead.  See Portability below.

But one might hope that `signal()` behaves sanely. However, there might be a data race because `main` might be interrupted before a *store* e.g. in a situation like this

```
if ( i > 10 ) { 
    i += j; 
}
void f(int signum) {
    i = 0;
}
```

If `main` is past the compare (or if the according registers do not get update if `main` was interrupted while compare), `main` would still to `i += j` which is a data race.

So where does this leave us? - Don't ever modify globals that get modified elsewhere in signal handlers if you cannot guarantee that the signal handler cannot interrupt this operation (e.g. disable signal handler for certain operations).