# Sigaction vs Signal

Tags: shell, signals, system-calls, sigaction

Can someone please explain the difference between sigaction and signal. I know they signal works differently depending on which machine you are working on i.e. Mac, Windows, or Linux and that sigaction works the same on all platforms. But my question is why is that, because I have tried using signal on different platforms and have gotten the same result. Also which one would you guys recommend using for better practice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between sigaction and signal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231912/what-is-the-difference-between-sigaction-and-signal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know few things about `sigaction` and `signal`. But what i know is that:

- `sigaction` call is more complex to use than `signal` call (as you already know).
- `sigaction`allows you to obtain more information about the signal received by your program (see `siginfo_t` structure).
- According to Michael KERRISK's book : ***"The Linux Programming Interface"*** (Ch. 22, page: 456) : "...it is good practice always to use `sigaction`, rather than `signal` to establish signal handlers."
- Finally (again from Michael KERRISK's book): "The Linux kernel contains an implementation of `signal` as system call, this implementation provides the older, unreliable semantics. However, `glibc` bypasses this system call by providing a signal library function that calls `sigaction` "

Hope it helps.