# extern with function call inside main

Tags: c, unix

While reading **Unix System Design** by Maurice Bach I came across below code snippet.

```
#include < signal.h>
char *cp;
int callno;

main() {
    char *sbrk();
    extern catcher();

    signal(SIGSEGV, catcher);
    cp = sbrk(O);
    printf("original brk value %u\n", cp);
    for (;;)
    *cp++ = 1; 
}


catcher(signo) {
    int signo;
    callno++;
    printf("caught sig %d %dth call at addr %u\n", signo, callno, cp);
    sbrk(256);
    signal(SIGSEGV, catcher); 
}
```

I got confused with two statements within main method

> char *sbrk();
>
> extern catcher();

I understand how `extern` works and I also know what `sbrk()` does but I couldn't understand why have they written `extern` before `catcher()` and also why is `char*` written before `sbrk()` call?

I got compilation error on gcc-4.8.4 on Ubuntu when compiling this code but code compiles without any errors in Mac. Why is this happening?

Comment: [You are reading something wrote in 1986........](http://160592857366.free.fr/joe/ebooks/ShareData/Design%20of%20the%20Unix%20Operating%20System%20By%20Maurice%20Bach.pdf)You should buy recent books that, at least, support c99

Comment: In older versions of C, there was a concept of "default type" - if the return type of function or the type of a variable was not specified, it was assumed to be `int`.

Comment: @LPs I understand that this a very old book but I just want to know what it means. @kfx How is that related to `extern` of `cather()` or `char *` of `sbrk()`

Comment: the `extern` is used to avoid declaring a prototype at the top of the file, I guess. **It is useless as the book where the code is written.**

Comment: The `extern` is there because you need _something_ to make it a function declaration rather than a function call. In this case, if default function return types are supported, it is equivalent to `int catcher();`.

Comment: It appears as it is just decalring these functions before they are called, may be thats what older compilers expected

Comment: The syntax of the `catcher` function is wrong. The `int signo;` should be _before_ the opening `{`. This is an old-style function definition without a prototype.

Comment: @IanAbbott You are correct! While copying I made a mistake (I tried to put it through `gcc` and modified it to remove errors)

Comment: @Nullpointer it has `extern` in front of it because otherwise that would be a function call, not a function declaration.

Comment: And `sbrk()` has the return type specified instead of `extern` because the return type of that one is not `int`. Writing `extern char *sbrk()` would give the same effect.

Comment: @kfx Thanks for the explanation. I have also edited my question to add that this code compiles correctly in Mac but gives error on Ubuntu. Why is this happening? Lastly, I don't think that the book is useless. It is an amazing book if you really want to learn about Unix concepts!

Comment: The program is invalid according to the current C standard. It was OK back when (30 years ago). Perhaps the Mac OS people need to catch up with the program, or something. If you really want have a go at the corpse of pre-ANSI C, your best bet is probably the *first edition* of K&R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char *sbrk();
extern catcher();
```

These are function declarations, not function calls. The code you are reading is old style (pre-ANSI), and in subsequent (c99 or newer) C standards they are no longer valid.

You should add an explicit return type to the declaration of `catcher()`. The current implicit declaration means it has an `int` return type. However, the correct signature for a signal handler specifies no return value. When we add an explicit return type, the `extern` keyword is no longer needed and it can be removed.

`sbrk` is actually declared in a regular header, so remove the declaration and `#include <unistd.h>`. However, `sbrk` is BSD (and part of SUSv2) and not a standard C function, so you need to activate the declaration with `#define _BSD_SOURCE` or `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE=500` before you include `unistd.h`.

`Printf` is declared in `stdio.h`, so let's include it. `%u` is used to print `unsigned int`. Pointers should be printed with the `%p` format specifier.

So, after some modernisation of the code:

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void catcher();

char *cp;
int callno;

int main(void) {
    signal(SIGSEGV, catcher);
    cp = sbrk(O);  // You sure this should be an O and not a 0?
    printf("original brk value %u\n", cp);
    for (;;)
        *cp++ = 1; 
}


void catcher(int signo) {
    callno++;
    printf("caught sig %d %dth call at addr %p\n", signo, callno, cp);
    sbrk(256);
    signal(SIGSEGV, catcher); 
}
```

Please note that you should avoid calling `printf` from within a signal handler. See for example [How to avoid using printf in a signal handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler) or [Signal Handlers and Async-Signal Safety](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/gen-26/index.html)

Comment: If you want to give a valid program, make `catcher` return `void`, include `<stdio.h>`, and use `%p` format for printing pointers. You may also need to define `_BSD_SOURCE` or a similar macro in order to enable `sbrk` and friends.

Comment: `int catcher();` -> `void catcher();`

Comment: @n.m. and kfx.  Thanks for helping to improve the answer.

Comment: `sbrk` is legacy SUSv2 function, not only BSD.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Added for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Klas Lindbäck's answer, there are other problems with this code under the current C and POSIX standards:

```
#include < signal.h>
char *cp;
int callno;

main() {
    char *sbrk();
    extern catcher();

    signal(SIGSEGV, catcher);
    cp = sbrk(O);
    printf("original brk value %u\n", cp);
    for (;;)
    *cp++ = 1; 
}


catcher(signo) {
    int signo;
    callno++;
    printf("caught sig %d %dth call at addr %u\n", signo, callno, cp);
    sbrk(256);
    signal(SIGSEGV, catcher); 
}
```

**Don't use `sbrk()`**

`sbrk()` has been removed from the POSIX standard.  It's no longer safe to use directly.  From [the Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/brk.2.html):

> Avoid using `brk()` and `sbrk()`: the `malloc(3)` memory allocation package
>   is the portable and comfortable way of allocating memory.

Why?  Because numerous C library functions often use `malloc()`/`calloc()`/`realloc()`/... internally, and [mixing `malloc()` and `brk()`/`sbrk()` calls in the same process is unsafe](https://www.google.com/search?q=mixing%20sbrk%20and%20malloc).  `malloc()` implementations often use `brk()`/`sbrk()` internally, so using `sbrk()` in your own code might very well corrupt your heap.

**Don't use `signal()`**

[`signal()` has significant issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/232711/4756299). It's not consistent at all. Use `sigaction()` instead.