# Why my sig_int() function can't prevent my function from exit in c?

Tags: c, unix

The codes is as below, and is the same as the one in book **apue3e**:

```
#include "apue.h"
#include "sys/wait.h"

static void sig_int(int);

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  pid_t pid;
  char buf[MAXLINE];
  int status;

  if (signal(SIGINT, sig_int) == SIG_ERR) {
    err_sys("signal error");
  }

  printf("%% ");
  while (fgets(buf, MAXLINE, stdin) != NULL) {
    if (buf[strlen(buf)-1] == '\n') {
      buf[strlen(buf)-1] = '\0';
    }

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
      err_sys("fork error");
    } else if (pid == 0) {
      execlp(buf, buf, (char *)NULL);
      err_ret("couldn't execlvp: %s\n", buf);
      exit(127);
    }

    if ((pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) < 0) {
      err_sys("waitpid_error");
    }
    printf("%% ");
  }
  exit(0);
}

static void
sig_int(int signo/* arguments */) {
  /* code */
  printf("Interrupted\n%%3 ");
}
```

So, my question is why this signal handler doesn't handle the `SIGINT` signal and exit immediately after pressing the **Ctrl+c** which i was testing on **archlinux**.

Comment: maybe not related but CTRL+C in MSYS (Windows) just kills the process (no signal is sent). What is your terminal configuration?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre definitely not related.

Comment: Try running under gdb. Give gdb `handle SIGINT nostop print pass` command and answer `y`. Then run the ptogram and press Ctrl-C.

Comment: It prints the `Interrupted\n %` and `[Inferior 1 (process 22039) exited normally]`, and may be  `fgets` returns `NULL` and causes it to exit normally, but why `fgets` returns `NULL` still confuses me. `errno` shows not cleaned `Interrupted system call`, so i think it may not be `EINTR`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [W]hy this signal handler doesn't handle the `SIGINT` signal and exit immediately after pressing the **Ctrl+c** which i was testing on archlinux.

Given

```
static void
sig_int(int signo/* arguments */) {
  /* code */
  printf("Interrupted\n%%3 ");
}
```

and

```
signal(SIGINT, sig_int)
```

Your process doesn't exit when you press **CTRL-C** for the simple reason your signal handler doesn't cause the process to exit.

You replaced the default `SIGINT` handler with your own, so the default action of exiting the process no longer happens.

Since you're running on Linux, I'll refer to the [GNU glibc documentation on termination signals](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html):

> **24.2.2 Termination Signals**
>
> These signals are all used to tell a process to terminate, in one way
>   or another. They have different names because they’re used for
>   slightly different purposes, and programs might want to handle them
>   differently.
>
> The reason for handling these signals is usually so your program can
>   tidy up as appropriate before actually terminating. For example, you
>   might want to save state information, delete temporary files, or
>   restore the previous terminal modes. Such a handler should end by
>   specifying the default action for the signal that happened and then
>   reraising it; this will cause the program to terminate with that
>   signal, as if it had not had a handler. (See [Termination in
>   Handler](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-in-Handler.html#Termination-in-Handler).)
>
> The (obvious) default action for all of these signals is to cause the
>   process to terminate.
>
> ...
>
> Macro: *int* **SIGINT**
>
> The `SIGINT` (“program interrupt”) signal is sent when the user types
>   the INTR character (normally *C-c*).

The [Termination in Handler glibc documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-in-Handler.html#Termination-in-Handler) states:

> **24.4.2 Handlers That Terminate the Process**
>
> Handler functions that terminate the program are typically used to
>   cause orderly cleanup or recovery from program error signals and
>   interactive interrupts.
>
> The cleanest way for a handler to terminate the process is to raise
>   the same signal that ran the handler in the first place. Here is how
>   to do this:
>
> ```
> volatile sig_atomic_t fatal_error_in_progress = 0;
>
> void
> fatal_error_signal (int sig)
> {
>
>   /* Since this handler is established for more than one kind of signal, 
>      it might still get invoked recursively by delivery of some other kind
>      of signal.  Use a static variable to keep track of that. */
>   if (fatal_error_in_progress)
>     raise (sig);
>   fatal_error_in_progress = 1;
>
>
>   /* Now do the clean up actions:
>      - reset terminal modes
>      - kill child processes
>      - remove lock files */
>   …
>
>
>   /* Now reraise the signal.  We reactivate the signal’s
>      default handling, which is to terminate the process.
>      We could just call exit or abort,
>      but reraising the signal sets the return status
>      from the process correctly. */
>   signal (sig, SIG_DFL);
>   raise (sig);
> }
> ```

Also, note that there can be significant differences between `signal()` and `sigaction()`.  See [What is the difference between sigaction and signal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231912/what-is-the-difference-between-sigaction-and-signal)

Finally, calling `printf()` from with a signal handler is undefined behavior.  Only async-signal-safe functions can be safely called from within a signal handler.  See [POSIX **2.4 Signal Concepts**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04) for the gory details.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I think my question is not about clean and recover, but just why it exist immediately. In my idea, i think it may be caused by `fgets` returns `NULL` after the signal handler, and the `errno` is not `EINTR`.

Comment: @handora Your program may exot because calling printf from signal handler is forbidden. Though in my experience it never caused a problem under Linux, and your program behaves as expected on my system, it is still not allowed. Your implementation may be different or I just might be too lucky. Remove `printf` from the handler and try again.

Comment: @handora  It's also possible that you send more than one `SIGINT` to your program - the default action of `signal()` is often to reset handling to the default after the handler is called once.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231912/what-is-the-difference-between-sigaction-and-signal for the problems with `signal()`.

Comment: I replaced the `signal` with `sigaction` and it turns out to be true, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem when I was learning apue, I think it might be a problem with `apue.h`, because after I removed this header file and added the header files required by the program, the program could run normally, probably like so:

```c
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAXLINE 4096

static void sig_int(int);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char buf[MAXLINE];
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    if (signal(SIGINT, sig_int) == SIG_ERR) {
        //err_sys("signal error");
    }
    printf("%% ");
    while (fgets(buf, MAXLINE, stdin) != NULL) {
        if (buf[strlen(buf) - 1] == '\n') {
            buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = 0;
        }
        if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
            //err_sys("fork error");
        }
        else if (pid == 0) {
            execlp(buf, buf, (char*)0);
            //err_ret("couldn't execute: %s", buf);
            exit(127);
        }
        if (pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0) < 0) {
            //err_sys("waitpid error");
        }
        printf("%% ");
    }
    exit(0);
}

void sig_int(int signo)
{
    printf("interrupt\n%% ");
}
```

This program can roughly get the desired results

Comment: This may *look* like it works but you are still calling `printf` from within your signal handler; and, as stated in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46154170/10871073), this is undefined behaviour ... so anything can happen (including the code *seeming* to work).

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks a lot for your reminder. I'll use the `write`  instead of the `printf`.