# Unable to reassign signal handler second time

Tags: c, signals

I have a simple code which uses two signal handlers for "Segmentation fault" signal. First one works when signal happens and after `longjmp`, I do reassigning of handler with second one for that signal. Unfortunately, the flow of code doesn't reach necessary handler and I still get "Segmentation fault".

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

int i;
int ci;

jmp_buf m_env_buffer;
jmp_buf max_env_buffer;

void handler(int signum){
    printf("sigsegv on i:[%d]", i);
    ci = (++i);
    longjmp(m_env_buffer,1);
}

void top_handler(int signum){
    printf("sigsegv on max i:[%d]", i);
    longjmp(max_env_buffer,10);
}

int main(void) {
    signal(SIGSEGV, handler);
    char * pstart = "loremipsum";

    int m_cell = 0;
    char m_cell_v;

    int point;

    point = setjmp(m_env_buffer);
    if(point == 0){
            for(i=0; ;i--){
                    m_cell_v = pstart[i];
            }
    }

    //this wasn't invoked
    signal(SIGSEGV, top_handler);
    point = setjmp(max_env_buffer);
    if(point == 0){
            for(i=ci; ;i++){
                    char cur = pstart[i];
                    if(cur==10)
                            printf("\n");
                    printf("%c",cur);
            }
    }
    puts("finish");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf` is not among the functions you may safely call from a signal handler.  That is, it is not async-signal-safe.  That might or might not be directly related to your observed behavior.

Comment: You are (intentionally, it seems) producing *undefined* behavior.  That doesn't stop just because you catch a SIGSEGV.  Your program cannot expect to continue afterward as if nothing happened. (Though it might do, because "undefined".)

Comment: Assuming you're running on Linux, first, [don't use `signal()`, use `sigaction()` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231912/what-is-the-difference-between-sigaction-and-signal).  Second, **read** and **understand** the [`setjmp()`/`longjmp()` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/longjmp.3.html).

Comment: If you're doing long jumps from a signal handler, consider whether you should be using [`sigsetjmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigsetjmp.html) and [`siglongjmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/siglongjmp.html) rather than [`setjmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setjmp.html) and [`longjmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/longjmp.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`signal()` should not be used. It has unreliable semantics. On your system the default action (termination) is performed when the second SIGSEGV is received. The second call to `signal()` has effectively no effect.

You should use `sigaction()` instead. In your case you can use the following function instead of `signal()`:

```
void set_signal (int signum, void (*handler)(int))
{
    struct sigaction act;

    act.sa_handler = handler;
    sigemptyset (&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_flags = SA_NODEFER;
    act.sa_restorer = NULL;

    sigaction (signum, &act, NULL);
}
```

In the future, read the documentation at your disposal. A good ressource is the [glibc manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/). It has a good chapter on [signal handling](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Signal-Handling.html).

Comment: while it's absolutely correct that `signal(2)` shouldn't be used, that isn't *it*. The second `SEGV` handler won't be called even if the OP's code is fixed to use `sigaction(2)` and not call signal-unsafe stdio functions while handling signals.

Comment: Yup, I didn't noticed the `SA_NODEFER`.