# Interrupt read call on signal

Tags: c, process, signals

I have to interrupt a read call if ctrl-c is pressed, using signal.
I wrote this (simplified) sample code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int should_stop = 0;

void sighandler(int signal)
{
    write(1, "\nctrl-c has been pressed\n", 25);
    should_stop = 1;
}

void read_function()
{
    char c;

    while (!should_stop)
        read(0, &c, 1);
    //Do some stuff and return someting
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, &sighandler);
    read_function();
    write(1, "read_function is over\n", 22);
    return (0);
}
```

As read is a blocking call (as far as I understood), the should_stop global variable will not be evaluated once read has been called.
So I don't know how I could interrupt the read call by pressing ctrl-c.

Another constraint is that I'm only allowed to use those functions:

```
- write
- read
- fork
- wait
- signal
- kill
- exit
```

So I can't use select to set a timeout value.
As I also need the return value of read_function, I can't use fork and just exit the process with a different signal handler.

Is there another way to interrupt the read call?

Comment: You read to not initialized buffer. You have no memory allocated for buf. That is UB. Are you sure that is the actual code?

Comment: This is simplified code, without any initialization / error checking, in my real code my buffer is initialized

Comment: You provided invalid code for the reason stated above, it doesn't comply with [mcve]. You can edit `char*` to be `char[1]` to make this code non-UB.

Comment: It was an error, I wanted to put a char c instead of a char *buf, I just edited the post

Comment: You have an illegal [access of a shared variable from a signal handler](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/SIG31-C.+Do+not+access+shared+objects+in+signal+handlers) that makes your code unpredictable. The compiler may optimize out every read of `should_stop` but the first because it knows that `read` can't modify `should_stop` and accessing `should_stop` from a signal handler is prohibited by the standard. Use `volatile sig_atomic_t` to comply with C standard section 7.14.1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what currently happens: when you send an interrupt signal from keyboard, the signal handler comes into action, writes the `\nctrl-c has been pressed\n` message to your console and sets the `should_stop` variable. Then, control is returned back to `read(0, &buf, 1)` statement. As the stdin is buffered, `read` won't be over until it meets a newline. If you press `Enter` afterwards — `read` reads one bit and returns. After that, a condition `should_stop` is checked again, and since it contains `1` value now — loop is over.

Now, we want to modify that behavior so that your program is gracefully shut down after SIGINT.

From `man 7 signal`:

```
If  a  blocked  call  to one of the following interfaces is interrupted by a
signal handler, then the call is automatically restarted  after  the  signal
handler  returns  if  the SA_RESTART flag was used; otherwise the call fails
with the error EINTR:
```

From `man 2 signal`:

```
certain  blocking  system calls are automatically
restarted if interrupted by a signal handler (see signal(7)).  The  BSD  se‐
mantics are equivalent to calling sigaction(2) with the following flags:

   sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
```

So, here's how we employ `sigaction(2)` for our case:

```
int main()
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_handler = sighandler;
    sa.sa_flags = 0;

    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);
    read_function();
    write(1, "read_function is over\n", 22);
    return (0);
}
```

This way, upon interruption by signal handler, `read(2)` returns with `EINTR` error and is not restarted.

`signal(2)` is generally inferior to `sigaction(2)` when it comes to portability of the code, you can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/232711/12139819)

Comment: I just corrected my mistake.
I know the behaviour of this code, but I want the signal caught to interrupt the read immediatly, without wait for a newline, and without even waiting for any character.
I also know the while statement can't solve my problem, it's here to illustrate what I'm trying to do

Comment: I'm not allowed to use sigaction, but that's the better answer for now

Answer (score 1):

It should work provided you declare the `should_stop` variable to be `volatile`. This will instruct the compiler to re-read it from memory on every access:

```
...
volatile int should_stop = 0;
...
```

Simply depending on your system, a `read` call may be restarted after a signal, and you will have to hit return after the Ctrl-C to end the program. By default, my FreeBSD 11 bos behaves like that.

If you want the `read` call not to be restarted, you should explicitely ask for that behaviour with `siginterrupt`:

```
...
signal(SIGINT, &sighandler);
siginterrupt(SIGINT, 1);
...
```

That way, the program will stop immediately after the Ctrl-C

Comment: `volatile sig_atomic_t should_stop = 0;` then? This way platform will choose underlying type for flag on its own. I get that it will be `int` on most platforms, but still.

Comment: It doesn't change anything, it already have this behaviour, I think the compiler doesn't optimize the while statement in my case, anyway, it's better to set should_stop as volatile you're right, but I want the signal to interrupt the read call immediatly, as I doesn't need to hit enter to make the function exit

Comment: @SergeBallesta

`CONFORMING TO 4.3BSD, POSIX.1-2001.  POSIX.1-2008 marks siginterrupt() as obsolete, recommending the use of sigaction(2) with the SA_RESTART flag instead.`

See my reply :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for! Unfortunatly, I'm not allowed to use this function, but maybe there's a something to give to the second signal's argument, to do same, let me check

Comment: Ok there isn't, I'll wait a bit in case of other ideas, else I'll mark your answer as correct as it's the best solution to my question for now

Comment: `sigaction(2)` is what you are looking for, it's even defined in the same header.  It allows the customization while `signal(2)` doesn't.

Comment: Yes but I'm not allowed to use it neither

Comment: @Bccyv: The Posix signal system is indeed configurable, but if you are not satisfied with the default and cannot configure it, I cannot imagine a way...

Comment: I think it's just not possible with the constraints I have, anyway, thanks a lot for taking this time helping me!