# C Language - Fail to reset SIGINT to default

Tags: c, signals

I am learning concepts of signals in the C language and met a problem when building a program for practices.
In the codes below, I am trying to reset `SIGINT` each time after the user press "ctrl-c" and to record how many times the user press "ctrl-c".

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<setjmp.h>

void handler(int signo);
jmp_buf buf;
int int_counting = 1;

void handler(int signo)
{
    signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
    int_counting++;
    // just tried to add another "signal(SIGINT, handler)" here
    // but saw the same result
    longjmp(buf, 1);
}

int main()
{
    if ((signal(SIGINT, handler) == SIG_ERR))
    {
        printf("Fail to catch the signal\n");
    }
    if (!setjmp(buf))
    {
        printf("Waiting for any signals ... \n");
    }
    else
    {   
        if (!setjmp(buf)){} // to reset "setjmp" to zero
        printf("Pressed 'ctrl-c' for %d times\n", int_counting);
        printf("Waiting for another signal\n");
        signal(SIGINT, handler);
    }
    while (int_counting <= 5)
    {
        sleep(1);
        printf("Processing ...\n");
    }
}
```

However, after the first signal no other signals can be sent to `handler` and the output looks like:
[image]

Could you anyone explains the reason?

Below are examples where it seems like the signal will not be **masked**.

```
// Examples for SIGALRM

#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int counting = 0;

void handler(int signo)
{
    printf("%d\n", counting);
    while (counting < 5)
    {
        signal(SIGALRM, handler);
        printf("%d\n", beeps);
        counting++
        alarm(1);
    }
}

void main(void)
{
    if (signal(SIGALRM, handler) == SIG_ERR)
    {
        printf("cannot catch SIGALRM\n");
    }
    alarm(1);
    while (counting < 5)
    {
        pause();
    }
    return;
}
```

```
// Example for SIGQUIT

#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<setjmp.h>

jump_buf buf;

void handler(int signo)
{
    signal(SIQQUIT, handler);
    longjmp(buf, 1);
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIQQUIT, handler);
    if (!setjmp(buf))
    {
        printf("begin ...\n");
    }
    else
    {
        print("restart ...\n");
    }
    while (1)
    {
        sleep(1);
        printf("waiting for sinals ...\n");
    }
}
```

Although my original question is answered but if any further explanation about
why those signals will not be **masked** (or please tell me that is how they work in C), it would be greatly helpful.

Comment: IMHO, in my humble opinion, you should first go through this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/signals-c-language/
If your objective is just to test signals then choosing a hello world is better. Focusing on  the objective of the program reduces unnecessary complexities in code.

Comment: By the way, trying to catch a signal inside a signal handler would not work.. signal would be pending by then.. it's like waiting for an interrupt inside an interrupt handler.. That could as well be your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I viewed your attached link already but did not find anything helpful ... Here I am trying to jump between the ```handler``` and the ```main``` but I do not understand why the ```signal(SIGINT, handler)``` in the ```else``` statement in ```main``` does not work

Comment: @breiters Because I cannot stack signals, I do not know how to run ```main => handler => main => handler``` iteratively like how I did by ```alarm```. Or maybe I can send out alarm in the ```SIGINT handler``` and work on the main part in ```SIGALRM handler```

Comment: @SanaeKochiya You could also simply return from the signal handler **without** a `longjmp` if you do not require to set the signal handler to `SIG_DFL` during signal handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the **signal mask** and therefore use `siglongjmp()` and `sigsetjmp()`.

This works as expected:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<setjmp.h>

void handler(int signo);
sigjmp_buf buf;
int int_counting = 0;

void handler(int signo)
{
    signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
    int_counting++;
    // just tried to add another "signal(SIGINT, handler)" here
    // but saw the same result
    siglongjmp(buf, 1); // 1: "fake" return value
}
int main()
{
    if ((signal(SIGINT, handler) == SIG_ERR))
    {
        printf("Fail to catch the signal\n");
    }
    if (!sigsetjmp(buf, 1)) // 1 (or any non-zero value): save sigmask
    {
        printf("Waiting for any signals ... \n");
    }
    else // this code is executed when the "fake" return value of sigsetjmp is non-zero
    {
        printf("Pressed 'ctrl-c' for %d times\n", int_counting);
        printf("Waiting for another signal\n");
        signal(SIGINT, handler);
    }
    while (int_counting <= 5)
    {
        sleep(1);
        printf("Processing ...\n");
    }
}
```

It is described in the man-page e.g. `man setjmp`:

> sigsetjmp() and siglongjmp() also perform nonlocal gotos, but provide predictable handling of the process signal mask

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I knew nothing about the library ```<setjmp.h>``` but this sounds like the so called "goto" (namely ```setjmp + longjmp```) combo can only works for once between two different contex.

Answer (score 1):

SIGINT is masked (blocked) during execution of your signal handler, and remains masked when you `longjmp` out of it.  That's why you don't see subsequent SIGINTs — the signal mask prevents their delivery.

The fix is three-fold.

First, use [`sigsetjmp(buf, 1)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigsetjmp.html) to save the calling mask and [`siglongjmp`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/siglongjmp.html) make the jump.  That will restore the signal mask to its expected value at that point in execution.

Second, use [`sigaction`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) rather than `signal`.  `sigaction` will force you to explicitly choose behavior like masking out signals during handler execution. [`signal`, on the other hand, does not mandate consistent behavior across platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/232711/132382).

Third, don't use `(sig)longjmp` at all.  You got into this trouble because you are issuing a non-local goto from within asynchronously executed user code (your handler).  It's very easy to make mistakes when reasoning about that kind of code.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. This is the first time when I heard about the ```SIGINT``` will be masked within the handler. May I ask is  ```SIGINT``` the only signal that will be masked? For example, it seems like ```SIGALRM``` will not be masked (an example can be found in the code inside this post) and ```SIGQUIT``` either.

Comment: @SanaeKochiya, if you use `signal`, the answer varies from platform to platform.  [Use `sigaction` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231912/what-is-the-difference-between-sigaction-and-signal/232711#232711) and you will _know_ the answers to your detailed questions.