# Why is my signal handler not working when I send two sigint signals Ctrl-C?

Tags: c, linux, unix, signals

I'm learning to write a signal handler in C for a Linux system. Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>
void sig_handler(int signum){


  //Return type of the handler function should be void
  printf("\nInside handler function\n");
}


int main(){
  signal(SIGINT,sig_handler); // Register signal handler
  for(int i=1;;i++){    //Infinite loop
    printf("%d : Inside main function\n",i);
    sleep(1);  // Delay for 1 second
  }
  return 0;
}
```

My question is, why when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> twice, the program stops? Shouldn't it be that everytime I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> the signal handler runs, so effectively the program should run forever?

In reality, this is my output, the signal handler is only called in the first <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, not the second time:

```
1 : Inside main function
2 : Inside main function
3 : Inside main function
4 : Inside main function
^C
 Inside handler function
5 : Inside main function
6 : Inside main function
7 : Inside main function
8 : Inside main function
9 : Inside main function
10 : Inside main function
^C
```

Comment: It is not safe to call `printf` inside a signal handler, as that function is not [async-signal-safe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).

Comment: Inside the signal handler, I suggest that you call [`write`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) instead, as that function is [async-signal-safe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).

Comment: I worked on a project that used an Access database backend.  The original author wrote a signal handler that called `printf`, and under certain circumstances instead of writing to `stdout` it would write to the .mdb file, hosing the database beyond repair.

Comment: What command are you using to compile the program?

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, a number of factors contribute to the behaviour of `signal`. Depending on the version of glibc, the defined [`feature_test_macros(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html), and whether or not the kernel version of the function is used, the results will differ between two polarizing behaviours, described as *System V semantics* and *BSD semantics*:

With *System V semantics*, when a signal handler is invoked, the *disposition* of the signal is reset to its default behaviour (`SIG_DFL`). Additionally, further delivery of the signal is not blocked during the execution of the signal handler.

With *BSD semantics*, when a signal handler is invoked, the *disposition* of the signal is **not** reset, and further delivery of the signal is blocked during the execution of the signal handler. Additionally, certain system calls will be automatically be restarted if interrupted by the signal handler.

Your version of `signal` appears to be supplying System V semantics. The signal disposition is reset after the first signal handler, and the following `SIGINT` terminates the program.

See [`signal(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) and its notes on portability for more details.

---

See [`signal-safety(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) for a list of functions that are safe to call from within a signal handler. `printf` is not an *async-signal-safe* function, and should **not** be called from within a signal handler.

Use [`write(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) instead.

---

The quickest fix is to call `signal` within the signal handler to once again set the signal *disposition* to the signal handler.

```
void sig_handler(int signum)
{
    (void) signum;

    char msg[] = "Signal handler called!\n";
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, msg, strlen(msg));
    signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);
}
```

The more robust solution is to use [`sigaction(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) to establish signal handlers, as its behaviour is more consistent and provides better portability.

A basic example:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t sig_count = 0;

void sig_handler(int signum)
{
    (void) signum;

    sig_count++;
    char msg[] = "Signal handler called!\n";
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, msg, strlen(msg));
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction sa = { .sa_handler = sig_handler };
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);

    while (sig_count < 5);
}
```

The default behaviour of `sigaction` is similar to that described by *BSD semantics*, with the exception that certain system calls will **not** restart when interrupted by the signal handler.

To enable this behaviour, the `.sa_flags` member of the `struct sigaction` should contain the `SA_RESTART` flag.

To mimic *System V* semantics, the `.sa_flags` member of the `struct sigaction` should contain the `SA_RESETHAND` and `SA_NODEFER` flags.

Comment: *To enable this behaviour, the .`sa_flags` member of the `struct sigaction` should contain the `SA_RESTART` flag.*  Note that won't cause all calls to be restarted.  For example, [`msgrcv()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgrcv.2.html): "a signal is caught, in which case the system call fails with `errno` set to `EINTR`;see `signal(7`).  (`msgsnd()` is never automatically restarted after being interrupted by a signal handler, regardless of the setting of the `SA_RESTART` flag when establishing a signal handler.)"

Comment: @AndrewHenle Hence, *"certain"*. Yes, [`signal(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) contains more details on how `SA_RESTART` relates to a magnitude of system calls, and `sigaction(2)` instructs the reader to consult `signal(7)` in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**: use `sigaction()`, not `signal()`, to install signal handlers.

As comments and other answers have observed, your signal handler has undefined behavior as a result of its call to `printf()`.  In the event that the signal handler is ever triggered, that gives the whole program UB, which makes it very difficult to reason about its observed behavior.

But consider this variation instead:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void sig_handler(int signum){
  static const char msg[] = "\nInside handler function\n";
  write(1, msg, sizeof(msg) - 1);
}

int main(){
  signal(SIGINT,sig_handler); // Register signal handler
  for(int i=1;;i++){    //Infinite loop
    printf("%d : Inside main function\n",i);
    sleep(1);  // Delay for 1 second
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I have switched from `printf` to `write` inside the signal handler, thereby removing the UB.  And if I compile it with

```
gcc -std=c11 htest.c -o htest
```

then **the resulting executable still exhibits the behavior you describe**: the first Ctrl-C is handled, but the second is not.

**HOWEVER**, if I instead compile with

```
gcc htest.c -o htest
```

then the resulting program intercepts *every* Ctrl-C I type, as I guess you were expecting.  So what's going on?

---

The problem revolves around the fact that the details of the behavior of the `signal()` function have varied historically.  For more detail, see the portability notes in [the `signal`(`2`) manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html), but here's a brief rundown:

In the original System V UNIX, the custom signal handlers installed via `signal()` were one-shots: when such a handler was triggered, the disposition for the signal was reset to its default, and the signal was not blocked during execution of the handler.

The System V behavior has some issues, so BSD implemented `signal()` differently in these respects: signal disposition is *not* automatically reset, and the signal *is* blocked during execution of the handler.  And additionally, in BSD, certain blocking system calls are automatically restarted if interrupted by a signal that does not result in the program terminating.

These differences mean that the only portable uses for the `signal()` function are for setting signal disposition to `SIG_DFL` or `SIG_IGN`.

Glibc supports *both* alternatives, and which one you get is controlled by feature test macros, which can be influenced by compiler command-line options.  It defaults to BSD semantics as long as the `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` macro is defined (`_BSD_SOURCE` prior to glibc 2.19).  Gcc defines that macro by default, but some command line options, notably the strict-conformance `-std` options, cause Gcc not to define it.  And that's why I could get different behavior depending on how I compiled the program.

On POSIX systems, the solution is to use the [`sigaction()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) function instead of `signal()` to register signal handlers.  This function has well-defined semantics for all the areas of behavioral difference described above, including a well-defined means to choose among them.  However, to get its declaration included in all cases, you will need to ensure that a different feature-test macro is defined.  For example:

```
// Manipulation of feature-test macros should precede all header inclusions
#ifndef _POSIX_C_SOURCE
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 1
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void sig_handler(int signum) {
    static const char msg[] = "\nInside handler function\n";
    write(1, msg, sizeof(msg) - 1);
}

int main(void) {
    // Register signal handler
    struct sigaction sa = { .sa_handler = sig_handler /* default sa_mask and sa_flags */ };
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);

    while (int i = 1; ; i++) {
        printf("%d : Inside main function\n",i);
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That will reliably get you a handler that is not reset when triggered, does have `SIGINT` blocked while it is being handled, and does not automatically restart system calls interrupted by the signal.  That will prevent the program from being killed via a `SIGINT`, though there are other ways it can be killed, such as via a `SIGKILL` (which cannot be blocked or handled).

Comment: Thanks for this. I knew there was a discrepancy, but not what it entailed.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `signal()`.  [Instead use `sigaction()`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231912/what-is-the-difference-between-sigaction-and-signal)

Per the spec, [*[w]hen a signal occurs, and [the second argument to `signal`] points to a function, it is **implementation-defined** whether the equivalent of a
`signal(sig, SIG_DFL);` is executed...*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html)

Historically, some UNIX flavors reset the signal disposition to the default behavior upon entry into the user-defined signal handler.  That meant that your first SIGFOO would invoke your handler, but your next one would trigger SIG_DFL behavior.  *Importantly, this is consistent with what you observe.*

Yes, `printf()` is unsafe (undefined behavior) to call in a signal handler.  In the code you provide, it might conceivably interrupt itself, which can lead to all sorts of nastiness.  In practice, people call `printf()` all the time in trivial programs to no great harm.  The fact that your behavior is repeatable suggests that you are getting deterministic behavior, and not dreadful eldritch magic undefined behavior.

`sigaction()` forces you to specify what kind of behavior you want when the user-supplied handler is invoked, and is thus superior to `signal()`.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, why when I hit Ctrl+C twice, the program stops?

---

### Undefined behaviour:

Your code invokes undefined behaviour because it calls a function (`printf`) that isn't async-signal-safe.¹

**From C11:**

> If the signal occurs other than as the result of calling the abort or
> raise function, **the behavior is undefined if the signal handler** refers
> to any object with static or thread storage duration that is not a
> lock-free atomic object other than by assigning a value to an object
> declared as volatile sig_atomic_t, or the signal handler **calls any
> function in the standard library other than the abort function, the
> _Exit function, the quick_exit function, or the signal function with the first argument equal to the signal number corresponding to the
> signal that caused the invocation of the handler.**

As per the C Standard, you can only call:

```
abort()
_Exit()
quick_exit()
signal()  /* With the first argument equal to the signal number the handler caught */
```

safely inside a signal handler.

---

The POSIX standard, however, specifies many more functions. So you can have `write()`, but not `printf()`.

---

[1] — *An async-signal-safe function is one that can be safely called from within a signal handler. (Linux man page)*

Comment: This is a plausible explanation for the observed behavior, and by nature it's impossible to refute, but there is a more likely one.