# Why is the ANSI C signal() function considered bad?

Tags: c, linux, signals

I see warnings on the function's documentation and sometimes when it's mentioned on Stack Overflow saying that it's better to use the POSIX `sigaction()` function. The warnings say that on Linux the function may not behave as expected. What do they mean by that?

One of these warnings is in the description section [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html).

Comment: did you see the NOTES section?

Comment: From the "Portability" section: "The only portable use of `signal()` is to set a signal's disposition to `SIG_DFL` or `SIG_IGN`."

Comment: It's all explained in detail on the page you linked

Comment: Oh yeah, I missed the notes section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want to do is catch a signal, once, `signal` is still kinda okay.

The question is, after you catch it, what happens if the signal comes in a second time?  Perhaps while the first signal handler is still running?

Under different systems, there have been different answers.

- Once upon a time, your signal handler got deregistered the first time it fired, meaning you had to reregister it every time, meaning there was a race condition if a second signal came in before you had a chance to reregister it.
- Since then, various improvements have been made, such as having further signals be *blocked* while a signal handler is running, and having them not always deregister themselves, so you don't have to reregister them.

But if you just call `signal`, you don't know which of these behaviors you're getting — but the differences probably matter to you.

`sigaction` gives you explicit, predictable control over all these details, and is therefore preferred.

See also the "Portability" subsection in the NOTES section in the man page you linked: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html#NOTES

See also this previous SO question: [What is the difference between sigaction and signal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231912)