# Map unallocated memory after SIGSEGV

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, mmap

After catching a SIGSEGV through a signal handler, I am trying to use `mmap` to map the address.  I can't figure out why `mmap` fails with `Cannot allocate memory` error.

Here is the C code. I am trying to run this on macOS.

```c
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *addr;

static void catch_function(int signo, siginfo_t *si, void *unused) {
  printf("Got SIGSEGV at address: 0x%lx\n", (long)si->si_addr);

  void *ptr = mmap(addr, 100, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                   MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANON | MAP_FIXED, 0, 0);

  if (ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("mmap");
  }
}

int main(void) {
  int page_size = getpagesize();

  if (signal(SIGSEGV, catch_function) == SIG_ERR) {
    fputs("An error occurred while setting a signal handler.\n", stderr);
    return 1;
  }

  addr = (void *)(page_size * 100);

  // trigger segfault
  *((int *)addr) = 1;
}
```

Comment: So which of the [meanings of ENOMEM](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/mmap.2.html) could this be? Probably "address specified by the addr parameter isn't available".

Comment: See the [documentation for mmap](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), and in particular the section titled "Using MAP_FIXED safely"

Comment: I don't know why you would want to do this, but `mmap`, `printf`, and `perror` are not *async-signal-safe* functions. Also, the usage of `signal` is not portable except for setting the signal disposition to `SIG_DFL` or `SIG_IGN`. Use `sigaction` instead.

Comment: Side note: use `sigaction()`, not `signal()`, to register signal handlers.  The only portable uses of `signal()` are to ignore a signal or reset it to its default disposition.  See [What is the difference between sigaction and signal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/231912/2402272).  Moreover, you *must* use `sigaction` to register a handler function with the signature you are using.  Handlers registered via `signal()` must have the signature `void f(int)`.

Comment: If code is trying to access memory that's not allocated, what problem do you think allocating memory at that location would solve?

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the **segmentation fault**(SIGSEGV) is the attempt to write to an invalid memory address.

In your case, I think the `addr` variable is set to a memory address that is not allocated.

Here's the updated code:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *addr;

static void catch_function(int signo, siginfo_t *si, void *unused) {
  printf("Got SIGSEGV at address: 0x%lx\n", (long)si->si_addr);

  void *ptr = mmap(NULL, 100, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, // Here
                   MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANON, -1, 0); // Here

  if (ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("mmap");
  } else {
    addr = ptr; // Here
  }
}

int main(void) {
  int page_size = getpagesize();

  if (signal(SIGSEGV, catch_function) == SIG_ERR) {
    fputs("An error occurred while setting a signal handler.\n", stderr);
    return 1;
  }

  addr = (void *)(page_size * 100);

  // trigger segfault
  *((int *)addr) = 1;
}
```

*(Didn't tested it yet)*

Comment: I don't think "not allocated" conveys what you mean to say.  Do you perhaps mean *already allocated* or *not available*?

Comment: In any case, even if this version of the `mmap()` call works -- which it very well might, depsite not being async signal safe -- the effect is not what I take the OP to want.  That is, I don't think they chose `MAP_FIXED` arbitrarily.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't figure out why `mmap` fails with `Cannot allocate memory` error.

That would be an `ENOMEM` error.  [The manual for MacOS's version of `mmap()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/mmap.2.html) documents these conditions under which `ENOMEM` will be raised:

> ```
>  [ENOMEM]          MAP_FIXED is specified and the address range specified
>                    exceeds the address space limit for the process.
>
>  [ENOMEM]          MAP_FIXED is specified and the address specified by
>                    the addr parameter isn't available.
>
>  [ENOMEM]          MAP_ANON is specified and insufficient memory is
>                    available.
> ```

You are trying to map only 100 bytes, in a process with a very small image to begin with, so the first and third alternatives both seem implausible.  That leaves the second -- **you used `MAP_FIXED`** (which you did) **and the address you asked for wasn't available**.  That should be understood as inclusive of *any* address in the 100-byte range starting at the requested address not being available for mapping.

The address you asked for was very low, so it's entirely plausible that the OS reserves it. Or that it was already using it for something else (protected from the program's attempt to read it).  You can reduce the likelihood of such issues (see below), but it is extremely difficult to eliminate the possibility altogether.

But that's not the only problem with this short code.  There is also at least:

- Given this function signature:

  > ```
  > static void catch_function(int signo, siginfo_t *si, void *unused) {
  > ```

  ... this call to [`signal()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/signal.3.html):

  > ```
  >   if (signal(SIGSEGV, catch_function) == SIG_ERR) {
  > ```

  produces undefined behavior because the type of the second argument is incompatible with the declared type (`void (*)(int)`) of the second parameter to `signal()`.  Your compiler should be warning you, and you should be paying attention to it.  If your compiler is *not* warning you about that issue then either turn up the warning level until it does, or get a better compiler.

  You should instead be using [`sigaction()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/sigaction.2.html) to register such a handler.  And to register *any* handler, really, because `signal()`'s behavior is non-portable except for resetting a signal to its default disposition.
- When you call `mmap()` with `MAP_ANON`, you generally should pass -1 as the file descriptor.  Some systems require that.  MacOS, on the other hand, attributes special significance to you passing a valid, open file descriptor.
- The `printf()`, `mmap()`, and `perror()` functions are not async-signal-safe, so calling them from a signal handler produces undefined behavior.  This is something that really does sometimes break in the real world.  That leaves you without any well-defined way to make the accessed address readable, so I see no portable way for your on-demand allocation idea to work.
- In the event that the `mmap()` call fails, so that you cannot make the value of `addr` a valid address, you should ensure that the program terminates.  If you don't, and if the system does not reset the disposition for `SIGSEGV` when the handler is invoked, then you will end up with a segfault loop.

But perhaps you have knowledge that on your particular system it is ok to call `mmap()` from a signal handler, or you want to act as if you did.  In that event, instead of choosing a random address to demonstrate with, a better strategy would be to allocate some memory and then deliberately perform out of bounds accesses relative to that allocation.  Maybe something more like this:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *addr;
volatile sigatomic_t stop = 0;

static void catch_function(int signo, siginfo_t *si, void *unused) {
  printf("Got SIGSEGV at address: %p\n", (void *)si->si_addr);
  stop = 1;

  void *ptr = mmap(addr, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                   MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANON | MAP_FIXED, -1, 0);

  if (ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("mmap");
    abort();
  }
}

int main(void) {
  int page_size = getpagesize();

  if (signal(SIGSEGV, catch_function) == SIG_ERR) {
    fputs("An error occurred while setting a signal handler.\n", stderr);
    return 1;
  }

  addr = malloc(page_size);
  if (!addr) {
    fputs("Initial memory allocation failed\n", stderr);
    exit(1);
  }

  // trigger segfault. It might take more than one attempt.
  unsigned int sum = 0;
  do {
    addr += page_size;
    sum += *(unsigned int *)addr;
  } while (!stop);

  // Ensure that the program has external behavior that depends
  // on the memory accesses, else the accesses could be optimized away.
  printf("The sum is %s\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: I think the problem with your code is that it attempts to access memory beyond the allocated region... since the `addr` variable is not properly initialized or allocated, accessing memory beyond the allocated region leads to a segmentation fault. We need to ensure that the `addr` variable is properly allocated and updated when accessing memory. Next:

Comment: Continue: So your loop should be something like this: `do {addr = malloc(page_size); sum += *(unsigned int *)addr;free(addr); addr += page_size;} while (!stop);`

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub, you seem to be missing the point: triggering a segfault via an out-of-bounds access is exactly the objective here.  The OP wants to *handle* such a segfault by creating a memory mapping at the erstwhile invalid address.  The point of the initial allocation is to influence the faulty address toward being in a part of the address space that the system is willing to map.  If that mapping is successful, then on return from the signal handler, the *then valid* access will go through.

Comment: To be clear, however: nothing in the C language spec provides any reason to think that this will work.  From that perspective, it absolutely has UB.  But with enough care, this kind of thing can be and is made to work fairly reliably on some specific implementations.